# How to change property of many buttons in WP7 using Foreach?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to change the property `Background` of many Buttons in WP7.

Can I write something like this:

```
Foreach (var item in (this.Content as Panel).Children)
{
    If (Element is Button)
    {
        Element.Background = Color.red;
    }
}
```

But this doesen't work, 
Element.Background doesen't exist...

Anyone know how to fix it???

Comment: Perhaps try write valid C# code for starters? A *basic tutorial* in C# would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
  //to be on the safe side first check
  if(this.Content == null || !(this.Content is Panel)
      return;

  foreach (var item in (this.Content as Panel).Children)
    {
        if (item is Button)
        {
            Button b = item as Button;
            b.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This didn't work.. program says "NullReferenceException was unhandled" at "(This.Content as Panel).Children)

Comment: So if `this.Content = null` this means there are no buttons inside it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it with

```
Element.BackColor = Color.Red
```

instead of

```
Element.Background = Color.Red
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through the controls, try binding their BackColor properties to something, be it a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged with a property that returns a SolidColorBrush, another control's BackColor property, or whatever you choose to bind to.  This can be done in silverlight without having to loop through the controls.  Let the system manage the control appearance instead of writing it yourself.